TLP292 Schematic Review
I am designing a circuit with TLP292. Below is the schematic.

The I/P is coming from a microcontroller it is either 0 V or 5 V.
The output current is 15mA to 20mA
May I know is this circuit is fine?
Will this 5 V turn on the optocoupler or not?

Can't tell. Are you shorting out the 26 V rail to ground with it or something else?

It is not ground.26V is going to a connector

Named GND? Please include the whole circuit. What's the load current?

Updated the question

No, your circuit is not fine. The TLP292 has a current transfer ratio of 50 % at 0.5 mA LED current, meaning that it will not be saturated and you can only expect 0.5((5-1.4)/10k)=0.18 mA on the collector.
You need to supply at least 20/0.5 = 40 mA to the LED to ensure proper operation, at which point you are well above recommended values, but below absolute max. Also possibly more than your MCU can supply without buffering. If your MCU and your load shares ground, I would recommend an N-MOSFET+P-MOSFET setup instead. If they are isolated, you'd be better off with either an optocoupler with higher current transfer ratio, or use the output to drive a PNP with higher beta.
Here is the MOSFET-solution. Feel free to tune the values. The Zener diode is needed since the P-MOSFET can't take 26 V on the gate.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thank you .If you don't mind could you please put a schematic of "I would recommend an N-MOSFET+P-MOSFET setup instead"

@Confused Updated.
